# CSS inheriting div width

Tags: css

I have essentially the following code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="stuff"></div>
</div>
```

The div "foo" contains a bunch of things which will fill it up giving it a certain width and force that width on the "parent" div. I would then like the div "stuff" to obtain the same width as what "foo" is forcing on "parent", so I can left-align things in "stuff" to match with "foo".

How is this done? If I set width to 100% on "stuff", then it'll give it the width of the whole viewport instead of what the parent has. Any ideas?

Comment: Please update your question following this guideline: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Child container elements that do not have a `width` specified for them should automatically conform to the value of their parent. If this is not the case for your example, please give a screenshot that shows otherwise

Comment: As @m_callens points out. Your `stuff` div should already have the same width: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfw6myyy/

Comment: @m_callens just to add the condition if the children are block elements, inline or inline-block doesn't have that behavior

Comment: Right. and even if the `.foo` div would be wider than the window (by giving it a specific width), its parent would still be only 100% wide, as would `.stuff`. So we do need a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.